# Stop Android Service from another package

Tags: android, bluetooth

Before someone tells me this cannot be done, I have done plenty of research on why on process cannot interfere with one another and under what conditions this is possible. Our problem is that the Bluetooth support between devices is inconsistent and the solution on some devices is to stop the existing Bluetooth service and run a separate app (BlueFTP) which is then able to listen on the freed port and manage OPP communication.

- `android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES` permission plus `ActivityManager.restartPackage()` doesn't work as it simply restarts the offending package.
- `Process.killProcess` does not work for the obvious reasons (read the API)
- `android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` permission plus `ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses()` is ignored because (I believe as per the API) the Bluetooth app is not considered a background app and therefore not eligible to be killed.

Currently if a client is having an issue with a specific phone, we get them to go to the running apps and force stop the offending OPP Service before refreshing BlueFTP so that the port listener starts. The offending service has more than one possible name depending on the phone and Android version.

So. The process is currently manual but I was hoping there would be a way to achieve this via code mirroring the force stop option in settings. A lighter option could be to assist in opening the settings for that service rather than needing to explain to clients how to get there, but I'd prefer a complete solution if one is available. 
Note that while our the dev phones have root access, the client phones will not.

Comment: Have you looked into the aosp code? How does Settings 'force stop' apps? Can you do the same or do they have special privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use implicit intents for your services in other apps to close them. It wouldn't need extra permissions as well, unless your service enforces a permission for it's access.

Oh, I overlooked the fact that it's a third party app. In that case, you can't really do much. Sorry.