# Stopping BluetoothOpp Service in Android

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I am experiencing the same issue as posted in the following question:

[Stop Android Service from another package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184973/stop-android-service-from-another-package)

Has anyone come up with any other workaround?  In my scenario, if the phone has the BluetoothOpp service running, the only way to get the bluetooth to work between the phone and my device, which is a digital pen, is to manually shutdown the BluetoothOpp service.  This poses a real challenge since the majority of my user base will not likely be savvy enough to understand this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I sympathize with the problem (yes, getting users to do this manually is not a good solution) but the answer should be no.  An app should not be able to shut down a system service (at least w/o explicit user authorization).

After all, OPP (object push protocol) has a valid purpose and is supposed to be available to receive objects pushed from another device.  If you kill it the user might get rather confused.  (And more personally, I have written an app once that depended on OPP being there and listening.)

One way to verify that would be to install some task killer apps and see if they can kill OPP, but I believe they can't.  If they can, then check which permissions they have.

And even if you find that something like the ADMIN privilege allows you do this, adding it to your app would scare users away.

Comment: This app is a bit of a special scenario.  We are essentially using the phone just to run this app.  It will never be for general distribution and only used for our customers on a few select phone models (ones that are "ruggedized").  Otherwise, I agree with you that it isn't good practice to shutdown system services.

Comment: Oh, OK.  I guess the upside of such a scenario is that you can use scary sounding permissions, but I'm not aware of any that would let you do what you want (other then ROOT, of course).

Comment: If I root the phone, how do I go about killing that process once rooted?